# Platform Specific Views in Sencha Touch

Tags: mobile, sencha-touch-2

I am evaluating Sencha Touch 2.2.1 for a hybrid application (on PhoneGap 2.6) that targets Android and iOS. One of the important factors for me is the ability of the framework to adhere to UX standards of each of the platforms. For example, iOS UX principal for tab bars is to have it at the bottom of the page, where as in Android, the standard is to have it on top.

Is it possible to write a single application in Sencha Touch 2, which would render differently on each platform at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use Sencha touch to find out which OS is this and render your elements accordingly. For example if you want to dock tab bar in bottom or top, it is controlled by `docked` property which can have value like this:

```
docked : Ext.os.is.Android ? 'top' : 'bottom'
```

Check out [Ext.os](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.os) class for more information